# How to use Windows 8.1 USB Installation Media as DISM Source?

Tags: windows, dism

Is it possible to use a Windows installation USB drive as the source for DISM? The USB installer was created using [Microsoft's Media Creation Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows8).

[This MS article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825020.aspx#BKMK_Specify) states:

> You can use a mounted Windows image from a WIM file as a source to
>   restore optional features and repair a corrupted operating system.

The answer in [this thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_install/how-to-repair-your-system-files-using-dism-and-sfc/1021b42a-09ff-41a0-a95a-48f3ee3ae699?auth=1) says to use the `install.wim` file on the installation media.

> 4.1 `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /source:WIM:X:\Sources\Install.wim:1 /LimitAccess`

But on a USB installation media, the file is called `boot.wim`, not `install.wim`.

I tried the syntax as in that thread:

`DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:WIM:F:\sources\boot.wim /LimitAccess`

and got

> Error: 87 An error occurred while processing WIM:F:\sources\boot.wim.
>   The specified path was not found.

[This article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh824869.aspx) states i can mount the .wim file, and point to the Windows directory inside it. That failed too:

`DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:C:\bootwim\Windows /LimitAccess`

gave:

`Error: 0x800f081f
The source files could not be found.`

What am i doing wrong?

*(Note, plz let me know if this is the wrong group for this question. I was told the only choices for Windows questions are ServerFault, and SuperUser. SuperUser is described as "for computer enthusiasts", and i think this question is beyond "computer enthusiast" level.)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The installer archive on a USB installer created with the MS Media Creation Tool is not a WIM file-- it's an ESD file: install.esd.

The solution is to mount the ESD, *or* extract the ESD, *or* convert the ESD to a WIM file.

I converted the ESD to a WIM file, using [NT-LITE free version](https://www.ntlite.com/download/). Then i was able to successfully perform the DISM command against this new WIM file.

Answer (score 4):

I've never used Microsoft's Media Creation Tool before, so I am making some assumptions here.  I *do*, however, work with OS imaging all the time using MDT, WDS, and SCCM (including the boot images those utilities create), so I am very familiar with the process and how Microsoft structures Windows install media in general.

That being said, there *should* be two .WIM files in the `\Sources` directory on the USB stick you have; `boot.wim` and `install.wim`.  `Boot.wim` is the WinPE install image, and `install.wim` is the operating system's core files.  This has been the source media structure for Windows since Windows Vista.

Check the sizes of the `.wim` files you have.  Your `boot.wim` file should only be a couple hundred megabytes in size.  `Install.wim` will be several gigs (3-4) in size.  If you do not have an `install.wim` file in the `\Sources` directory on your USB stick, and your `boot.wim` files is only a couple hundred megs like it should be, then I would say that the USB stick is malformed somehow.

If your `boot.wim` file is very big (this is where my lack of knowledge on the MS Media Creation Tool would come into play), then the `install.wim` file you're looking for is probably inside it (although I've never seen install media created this way).  If this is the case, then you will need to either mount the `boot.wim` file to a directory on your hard drive (also using DISM), or extract it using 7-Zip or a similar tool that understands `.wim` files.

Comment: your answer, tho not the solution, gave me the idea to search for the largest file on the installer media. Solution below. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [here](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-use-dism-command-line-utility-repair-windows-10-image), but not something I can try right now because the windows image downloads are failing me:

```
DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:repairSource\Install.esd
```

should use the esd (adapt the folder name as needed of course), and adding /LimitAccess will "limit the use of Windows Update", whatever that means...